# Send String from service to activity using broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcast, receiver

im trying to send string from service to activity - but i cant do this. I found a lot of examples - and nothing not work.
Im using LocalBroadcastManger
i add this part of code to mainactivity.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             Logger.e("RECEIVEEEEER!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    };
```

and in onResume/onStart

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(
                mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("myIntentKey"));
```

and in service i add this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent("myIntentKey");
intent.putExtra("key", "keyfromservice");        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent)
```

Service start from push notification . Main activity  extends from "CordovaActivity". 
When code in service start - my broadcast receiver not get message(or call blabla) But if sendBroadcast run from main activity then this code work. Guys whats wrong ?
Main problem that in service i have some calculation after i need send this new calculation to activity for showing on main UI. Please any can help me ? why i cant send String from Service to Activity.

**UPD**
i have activity which extends from cordovaActivity( so my UI its webpage). I write js part which i call from java for update data on screen.
When pushNotificaiton coming - i start service here

```
 @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
```

for understanding logs in manifest for service i write

```
 <service android:exported="false" android:name=".services.MyService" android:process=":myProcess">
```

so in logcat i can pick my process for monitoring.

**SOLUTION**
when i remove

```
android:process=":myProcess"
```

broadcast start working as need. Thank to @Mike.M

Comment: did you try to replace the `getApplicationContext()` with `this` in both places? The Context of the Service and the Activity should be the right one.

Comment: yes i tried this. No changes

Comment: well the rest of the code seems right. Did you check the service really calls the code and the receiver is not unregistered? No other idea from my side, sorry.

Comment: did you try with context.sendBroadcast(intent)? I think the notification Service runs in another progress, so LocalBroadcastManager will not work

Comment: for service i create another process . like android:process=":myNewProcess" can be its problem ?

Comment: Yep, that's your problem. `LocalBroadcastManager` doesn't work across separate processes.

Comment: how i can fix it ,?

Comment: As noted in answers on the duplicate linked at the top of your post, either run the `Service` in the same process by removing that attribute from the `<service>` element, or use some sort of IPC, like sending the broadcasts on a `Context`, instead of using `LocalBroadcastManager`.

Comment: @MikeM. thank Mike , removing android:process=":myProcess" - fixed my problem.